# Angular: Why color CSS property setting propagates down to the nested component?

Tags: angular

Here is what Angular [guide](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#style-scope) says about style scope and inheritance:

> The styles specified in @Component metadata apply only within the template of that component. 
>   They are **not** inherited by any components **nested** within the
>   template nor by any content projected into the component

And if style propagation down the nesting-tree is desired, users are advised  to explicitly

> Use the /deep/ shadow-piercing descendant combinator to force a style
>   down through the child component tree into all the child component
>   views.

```
// For example, this should make all h3 elements down the nesting-tree italic: 

    :host /deep/ h3 {
      font-style: italic;
    }
```

Let's have a look at this sample setup:

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `
        <div class="my-container">
            <app-hello></app-hello>                // <-- a nested component
            This is local txt in app component
        </div>
    `,
    styles: ['.my-container { color: red; }']
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

**hello.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello Component!</h1>`
})
export class HelloComponent {}
```

**Expected:** the text in `app-component` is red, the text in `hello-component` is black

**Observed:** Both texts are red. **Why ?**

Demo in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/style-inheritance)

Comment: In your example it's just basic CSS inheritance, nothing to do with angular

Comment: @David, I wouldn't agree - the guide doesn't say a basic CSS is outside of the scope of Angular, on the contrary - it explains how in the context of Angular the CSS inheritance should happen. And from what I observe there is a deviation - what I am trying to find out is - what are the causes of it ( a bug, a deviation that need to be kept in mind or sth else)

Comment: See my answer if it helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example, it's just basic CSS inheritance: you say that the div's color is red, and you don't explicitly specify any other color for that div's child elements. So of course your child component is going to have red text; it's just CSS' normal behaviour.

Now say you add a `h1` to your parent element and add a rule to change its color to green.

```
template: `
  <div class="my-container">
  <h1>hellllooooo</h1>
    <app-hello></app-hello>
    This is local txt in app component
  </div>`,
 styles: ['.my-container { color: red; } h1 {color: green}']
```

In this case, the h1 from the parent will be green, but this rule won't leak to the child's h1, which will still be of inherited (red in your example).

This is exactly what the bit you quoted means

> The styles specified in @Component metadata apply only within the template of that component. They are not inherited by any components nested within the template nor by any content projected into the component

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/style-inheritance-7zewce?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

**Edit**: created another demo, demostrating `/deep`

**parent.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
        <app-hello></app-hello>
      <div class=container2>Text inside container2 div in parent - green</div>
  `,
  styles: ['.container2 {color: green}']
})
```

**child**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-hello',
  template: `
  <div class=container2>Text inside container2 div in child </div>`,

})
```

As is, the content is the child element will be **black**, not green. The parent style does not leak. Now, it you modify parent style to

```
styles: ['/deep/ .container2 {color: green}']
```

Then the color in the child div will be green.

[2nd stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/style-inheritance-wtw6rd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: you are not addressing the fact that <app-hello> is nested component, and hence it should not inherit color from its parent as the guide says.

Comment: Yes I am, with the h1 example. The CSS rule only applies to parent's h1. That's what the guide means.

Comment: @zaggi I added another stackblitz demo to help you understand better

Comment: @David, thank  you, have a look at my summary - is it in line with what you are saying ?

Comment: @zaggi yeah it's similar

Answer (score 0):

The meant style propagation works this way.

If there is a class `.my-class {...}` defined in a parent component, the stiles can propagate to a child:

- Via CSS inheritance (like color property is inherited)
- If the style definitions in the parent are explicitly marked 'visible' to the child for example via 
  `:host /deep/ .my-class { ... }`

**Takeaway**: shadow DOM doesn't stop CSS inheritance (p.1), it stops class naming propagation which can be enabled as in (p.2)

Demo in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/style-inheritance-solved)